# How can I sum array values by unique key?

Tags: perl

For example

```
array (
product1_quantity => 5,
product1_quantity => 1,
product2_quantity => 3,
product2_quantity => 7,
product3_quantity => 2,
)
```

with result:

```
product1_quantity - 6, 
product2_quantity - 10, 
product3_quantity - 2
```

Thanx!

---

sorry, guys

stupid example, instead this really

Array ( [0] => Array ( [product1] => 7 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product1] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [product2] => 3 )
)

?

Comment: Uhm language? Normally you can have only one value per key. So the array you provide is not even valid.

Comment: I don't know *any* language in which it is possible to have the same key for different values.

Comment: @felix, neo - those might be just some tuples

Comment: Let me see if I understand now. You want an array each element of which is an array each element of which is a key/value pair? Or is each element of the inner array a set of key/value pairs? Also: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Perl allows for easy interchangeability between arrays and hashes, as hashes evaluates in the whole are reported as arrays where every two items makes a key/value pair.  Thus, you can do stuff like:
my @array = ( this => 'that', foo => 'bar', this => 'other' );
my %hash = @array; # Two keys, "this" gets overwritten.

Comment: Are you sure this is perl? It looks a lot more like PHP actually: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull items off two at a time, and add to hash.

```
my @array = (
        product1_quantity => 5,
        product1_quantity => 1,
        product2_quantity => 3,
        product2_quantity => 7,
        product3_quantity => 2,
);
my %sums;
while (@array and my ($k,$v) = (shift(@array),shift(@array)) ) {
        $sums{$k} += $v;
}
```

Comment: whoops, missed that this is basically IDENTICAL to other answer, who beat me by two hours.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You'd want something similar to:

```
  use Data::Dumper;
  my @input = ( product1_quantity => 5,
                product1_quantity => 1,
                product2_quantity => 3,
                product2_quantity => 7,
                product3_quantity => 2,
              );
  my %output;

  while (my $product = shift(@input) and my $quantity = shift(@input)) {
    $output{$product} += $quantity;
  }

  print Dumper %output;
```

This spits out:

```
$VAR1 = 'product2_quantity';
$VAR2 = 10;
$VAR3 = 'product3_quantity';
$VAR4 = 2;
$VAR5 = 'product1_quantity';
$VAR6 = 6;
```

Be warned though -- if you've got any undefs in your quantity values this is going to break hard. You need to have an even numbered length array of product/numeric quantity pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_array;
foreach p in array:
  if(new_array.contains(p.key))
    new_array[p.key] += p.value;
  else
    new_array[p.key] = p.value;
```

new_array will contain the sums

Comment: Perl wasn't mentioned in the original post when I wrote this - see the revision history for the post.. "thanks" for -1

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
my %hash = ();
$hash{'product1_quantity'} += 5;
$hash{'product1_quantity'} += 1;
$hash{'product2_quantity'} += 3;
$hash{'product2_quantity'} += 7;
$hash{'product3_quantity'} += 2;

say join ",\n", map { "$_ - $hash{$_}" } keys %hash;
```

Output is:

```
product2_quantity - 10,
product3_quantity - 2,
product1_quantity - 6
```

The order is different, but you could force it to be "in order" by adding sorting:

```
say join ",\n", map { "$_ - $hash{$_}" } sort {$a cmp $b} keys %hash;
```